# RingtonePicker with ability to pick any mp3 files

Tags: android

Custom ringtones for users
I have created a ringtone picker as follows

```
public void selectRingtone(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
        intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE, "Select your ringtone:");
        intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_SILENT, false);
        intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_DEFAULT, true);
        intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE,RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALL);
        startActivityForResult( intent, 5);
    }
```

This shows the list of sounds identified as ringtones by android. I want to give the user the ability to select their on sound for eg. one list item would be browse for sound, on clicking this the user can go to file manager the user can point to an mp3 file to set as their ringtone. 
How can I achieve this?